# Creating/appending Numpy Array

Tags: arrays, numpy, stack, append

I have two numpy arrays that are shaped (8760,1) that I want to combine into a single array that is (8760,2) and then from that, filter out any values of zero that might be in first index column, or gauge in the "data" so that I can do statistical manipulation with the temp array.  I have tried np.stack and then attempted to filter out any zero values that way, but ended up with my temp array being 3D rather than still 2D.

```
data=np.stack((mb, gauge), axis=-1)
dta = data[:,data!=0]
idx = np.where(data[:,1]>0)
temp = data[idx,:]
```

I know I could filter out the zeros from gauge first, but I want to preserve the index values that go along with the mb array

Comment: `hstack` would be better if you want 2d

Answer (score 0):

`np.stack` joins along a newly created axis. Thus your arrays become 3D.

To join along an existing axis, you could use `np.concatenate`:

```
a1 = np.empty((100, 1))
a2 = np.empty((100, 1))
a3 = np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1) # will give a (100, 2) array
```